# How to check if a web file exists or not by using golang?

Tags: file, http, go

I want to check if a large file exists on a web server using golang :

```
resp, err := http.Get("http://aa.com/aa.mp4")
if err != nil {
   return false
  }
if resp.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
    return false
}
```

I can get what i want, but the `aa.mp4` is a large file, so this way looks nonoptimal. Is there another way?

Comment: That's not how HTTP works: HTTP as no notion of "file exists on webserver". Depending on the server you could try a HEAD request.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do a HEAD request instead [http.Head()](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Client.Head)

It is the same as a GET but won't download the body.

```
resp, err := http.Head("http://aa.com/aa.mp4")
  if err != nil {
   return false
  }
  if resp.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
    return false
  }
```

From the HTTP spec:

> The HEAD method is identical to GET except that the server MUST NOT return a message-body in the response